# No se cargan valores de un campo Array a un Input en Angular

Tags: angular

hola necesito ayuda por favor, quiero editar atributos de un libro y para ello necesito que se cargen los datos en cada uno de los inputs, el problema sale cuando los campos son Arrays, al momento que que realizo un `console.log(libros.autores[0].nombre)` imprime el dato sin ningún problema, pero cuando le asigno al input no imprime nada, sigue vacío, y no entiendo por que, si alguien me ayuda le estaría muy agradecida, autor se puede llenar por input dinamicos

component

```
 Miformulario: FormGroup;

   constructor(private libroservice:LibroService, 
     private fb:FormBuilder, private router:Router, 
     private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,
     private spinner:NgxSpinnerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
     let aux= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cuenta")); 
this.Miformulario= this.fb.group({
  isbn:[''],
  titulo:[''],
  stock:[],
  precioUnitario:[],
  descripcion:[''],
  autores:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),
  generos:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),
  editoriales:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),   
  cuenta:aux.idCuenta,     
 });
   this.cargar();    
 }

 onSubmit(formValue: any){ 

const libro= new Libro();

libro.isbn=formValue.isbn;

libro.titulo=formValue.titulo;
libro.stock=formValue.stock;
libro.precioUnitario=formValue.precioUnitario;
libro.descripcion=formValue.descripcion;   
libro.autores=formValue.autores;
libro.generos=formValue.generos;
libro.editoriales=formValue.editoriales;
libro.cuenta.idCuenta=formValue.cuenta;
this.libroservice.uploadImg(this.imagen,libro.isbn).subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.libroservice.createLi(libro).subscribe
      (resp=>this.router.navigate(['/lista']));       
    },
      err=>{
       this.spinner.hide();
       Swal.fire('Alerta',`Imagen No subida`, 'warning' );
       this.reset();
      }
     );
    }
```

Aqui Cargo los Datos para editar

```
 cargar():void{
//const libro= new Libro();
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
  b=>{
    let id = b['id'];
    if(id){
      this.libroservice.get(id).subscribe(
        (ac=>{
            this.libro = ac;
            console.log(ac);
              this.Miformulario.patchValue({
                isbn:[ac.isbn],
                titulo:[ac.titulo],
                stock:[ac.stock],
                precioUnitario:[ac.precioUnitario],
                descripcion:[ac.descripcion], 
                autores:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:[ac.autores[0].nombre]})]),//aqui no funciona
                generos:[ac.generos[0].nombre],///asi tampoco funciona, pero si hago un console.log dentro, si imprime el valor en consola


                })
             console.log(ac.generos[0].nombre)} ///aqui imprime el dato del array sin ningun problema
             

              ));
    }})
  }
```

/////////

```
    get getnombreautor(){
            return this.Miformulario.get('autores') as FormArray;
     }
    addnombreAutor(){
      const control=<FormArray>this.Miformulario.controls['autores'];
      control.push(this.fb.group({nombre:[]}));
    }
   removeAutor(index:number){
      const control=<FormArray>this.Miformulario.controls['autores'];
      control.removeAt(index);
    }
```

HTML

```
            <div class="mb-3">
                   <label for="autor" class="form-label">Autor(es)</label>
                    <div formArrayName="autores">
                         <div *ngFor="let item of getnombreautor.controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
                           <input formControlName="nombre" type="text" 
                   class="form-control" id="nombre"><a class=" boton menos btn btn- 
               link" (click)="removeAutor(pointIndex)"></a>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                         <a class=" boton mas btn btn-link" (click)="addnombreAutor()"></a>
                       </div>
```

no entiendo el por que, por favor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Un FormArray es un  array de AbstractControl.es una matriz de controles. Solo puede aplicar patchValues a formControls existentes o deberan ser creados

```
{ "editorial": "alfa", "autores": [ { "nombre": "Krishm" } ] }
```

Para ello tener en cuenta que:
en el FormArray..patchValue():

requiere de addAutor()
Mientras para editorial no lo requiere  ver codigo:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


class Autor{
  nombre!:string
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-arry',
  templateUrl: './form-arry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-arry.component.scss']
})
export class FormArryComponent implements OnInit {
  Miformulario: FormGroup;
  
constructor(private afb:FormBuilder) {
      this.Miformulario= this.afb.group({
      editorial: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ]),
       autores:this.afb.array([])
       })     
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cargarDefoult()
  }
  get editorial():FormControl{
    return this.Miformulario.get('editorial')as FormControl
  }
  get  autores():FormArray{
    return   this.Miformulario.get("autores") as FormArray
  }
  cargarDefoult() {

    this.patchEditorial();
    this.patchAutor();
  }
 patchEditorial(){
    this.Miformulario.patchValue({editorial:'alfa'})
  }
  newAutor():FormGroup{
    return this.afb.group({
      nombre:''
    })
  }
  addAutor() {
        
        this.autores.push(this.newAutor());
    }
  
  patchAutor() {
     //requiere de addAutor()
    this.addAutor()
    this.autores.patchValue([{ nombre: 'Krishm' }])
  }
    onSubmit() {
     this.Miformulario.reset()
  }
  
}
//vista
{{this.Miformulario.value | json}}
<form [formGroup]="Miformulario" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
        Editorial: <input formControlName="editorial">
        <label *ngIf="editorial.hasError('required')"> Enter Editorial. </label>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="autores">
    <div *ngFor="let autor of autores.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" >
    
        <p>
            <b>autor: {{i}}</b>
          </p>
          <p>autor nombre :
            <input type="text" formControlName="nombre">
          </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    

    <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```